# Why shall I obfuscate the ids of my records in rails?

Tags: security, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cancan

As I am using CanCan gem, I check if the required record is created by the current user, if not, I redirect to another action ..

So, why its important to encrypt the id sent via routes?

Is it that dangerous issue to keep it simple like this: ?

```
http://www.mydomain.com/posts/5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never heard anyone claim that obfuscating ids improves security.  Sounds like [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

Can you cite a source who claims that ids should be obfuscated?

Comment: No, but I often read questions of people trying to encrypt ids, and I see abstract answers without any explanation of why they should do so..

Comment: @simo I think if you feel that you need to encrypt your id to make your app secure, there is some other security flaw that needs to be addressed. As long as the data in the querystring isn't sensitive (social security number, password, etc) and you do authorization checks when data is requested (make sure the current user has permission to see the data associated with the specified id), then there shouldn't be a problem with putting ids in the querystring.

Comment: ids in the querystring are for record's id in the db, they are not related to user's sensitive data, only db ids ..